# Dojo duplicate ID error when instantiating a widget programmatically, but not declaratively

Tags: javascript, dojo

I'm using Dojo 1.10.

I'm trying to test a custom widget, but I get an error about a duplicate ID when I add it programmatically in my HTML file. Adding it declaratively works OK. In the past I've gotten that error when I accidentally used an ID attribute in a widget template, but I don't have an ID in this template. Here's a pared-down example:

demo/TestWidget.js

```
define([
  "dojo/_base/declare",
  "dijit/_WidgetBase",
  "dijit/_TemplatedMixin",
  "dijit/_WidgetsInTemplateMixin",
  "dojo/text!./template/TestWidget.html",
  "dijit/layout/ContentPane",
], function(declare, _WidgetBase, _TemplatedMixin, _WidgetsInTemplateMixin, template) {
     return declare([_WidgetBase, _TemplatedMixin, _WidgetsInTemplateMixin], {
       baseClass: 'TestWidget',
       templateString: template,
     });
   });
```

demo/TestWidget.html

```
<div data-dojo-attach-point="containerNode">
  <div data-dojo-type="dijit/layout/ContentPane">
    Random Stuff
  </div>
</div>
```

index.html:

```
<head>
  <script>
    var baseloc = location.pathname.replace(/\/[^/]+$/, "");
    var dojoConfig = {
      parseOnLoad: true, async: true,
      packages: [ { name: "demo", location: baseloc + "/demo" } ]
    };
  </script>

  <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/dojo/1.10.4/dojo/dojo.js"></script>
  <script>
    require([ "demo/TestWidget.js", "dojo/domReady!" ], function(TestWidget) {
        var widget = new TestWidget({ }, 'testnode');
    });
  </script>
</head>

<body class="claro">
  <div id="testnode"></div>
</body>
```

For the above code, I'm getting the error "Tried to register widget with id==dijit_layout_ContentPane_0 but that id is already registered". But if I delete the TestWidget instantiation in the script and replace 'testnode' with:

```
<div data-dojo-type="demo/TestWidget"></div>
```

it works OK. Any ideas what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: I don't think `domReady!` ensures that `parseOnLoad` has finished. Try using old-fashioned `ready`. Or call `parse` explicitly and create your widgets after it finishes.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, Roy. I had tried that before with the same result, but this time it worked when I also set `dojoConfig.parseOnLoad = false`. If you want to add this as an answer, I'll accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the problem is that parsing is going on while the new element is being created, due to `parseOnLoad` being true. If you can set it to false and call `parse` explicitly if needed, you should be able to avoid it.

Answer (score 1):

Try having unique id for the content pane you have in the template :

```
<div data-dojo-attach-point="containerNode">
  <div data-dojo-type="dijit/layout/ContentPane" data-dojo-id=myContentPane_{id}>
    Random Stuff
  </div>
</div>
```

Pass the id to the Widget in the constructor so that it is replace in the template. Make sure the id is unique for each instance.

My understanding says,in declarative approach unique id is created automatically if no id is mentioned explicitly in declarative syntax.